# How to Parse Pandas ExcelFile sheets with generic headers

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, indexing

I have many excel files with multiple sheets where the first row of data are not headers but data. How can I parse each sheet without specifying a header row, and the default not being 0. Having the first row as my headers is a pain.

Failing that, what is the best way to insert a column index into the first row of data?

My code is simple:

```
import pandas as pd
path_list #list of paths to .xls files
data_sheets = [] #container for parsed sheets
for file_ in path_list:
    excel_file_obj = pd.ExcelFile(file_)
    for sheet in excel_file_obj:
        data_sheet = excel_file_obj.parse(sheet)
        data_sheets.append(data_sheet)
```

I cant for the life of me figure out how to get the column index into the first row index. I basically want a `df.reset_index(False)` type solution but for columns. Does such a thing exist?

One extremely hackish way round would seem to be to do this for each data sheet:

```
first_row = data_sheet.columns
generic_cols = ['col' + str(x) for x in xrange(len(data_sheet.columns))]
data_sheet.index = [x for x in xrange(1, len(data_sheet) + 1)]
data_sheet.columns = generic_cols
for_concat = pd.DataFrame({col : val for col, val in zip(generic_cols, first_row)}, index = [0,])
new_sheet =pd.concat([for_concat, data_sheet])
```

There must be a better way. All help appreciated...

Comment: I believe you can set you header=None in your parse() that will use some default '0,1,2' type of column names.  Then you can change names before or after your concat

Comment: Hmmm... I dont think thats the key. Still defaults to row 0. Would be a super handy (and logical) option though.

Comment: If it does not do that, I think that is a bug (with csv files, specifying `header=None` does the desired behaviour)

Comment: Specifying `header=None` works for me with pandas 0.15.2. What version do you have?

Comment: I am also on 0.15.2  @joris.  header=None works with parse() and read_excel()

Comment: I see! I am 0.14. Guess I need to update myself! Thanks